# Python: How to re-use list comprehensions after they are created in an expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

How could I reuse the same list in an expression which is created using a list comprehension with an if else expression? Achieving it in a single statement/expression (without using any intermediate variable)
i.e. `index = 0 if [listcomprehension]` is empty else get first element of the list comprehension without re-creating it

```
carIndex = [index
            for index, name in enumerate([car.name for car in cars]) 
            if "VW" in name or "Poodle" in name][0]
```

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham you wouldn't, you would get a default value instead.

Comment: what is the default?

Comment: you can create the list then use something like  `ele = carIndex[0] if carIndex else 0`

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I would prefer to do it in one statement/expression rather than on multiple lines

Comment: Your question asks for a `clean way`, but then you write that you `prefer to do it in one statement/expression rather than on multiple lines.`. Some people (including me) think these two requirements are often in conflict... :-}

Comment: This doesn't even work. `car` contains `cars[-1]` on every iteration

Comment: @Frerich Raabe okay ill remove that statement as it is subjective

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a generator expression and next with a default value of 0, if you are not going to store the list creating one is pointless:

```
carIndex = next((index for index, name in enumerate(car.name for car in 
cars if "VW" in car.name or "Poodle" in car.name)),-1)
```

Your original logic will always return 0 if there is  a match so I am not sure if that is what you want. This will actually return the index of the car that matches the name in cars:

```
carIndex = next((index for index, car in enumerate(cars) 
if any(x in car.name for x in ("VW","Poodles"))), -1)
```

You first example is equivalent to:

```
carIndex = next((0 for _ in (car for car in 
cars if "VW" in car.name or "Poodle" in car.name)),-1)
```

Which would simply become:

```
carIndex = 0 if any("VW" in car.name or "Poodle" in car.name for car in cars) else -1
```

Comment: Ah neat too! I didn't know `next` had a `default` value available. Nice!

Comment: Yes that seems like what Im looking for.

Comment: @Har, it is more efficient also, if you don't assign any name to the list you cannot use it anywhere so creating a whole list to get a single element would be redundant.

Comment: I think this could be shortened to `next((index for index, car in enumerate(cars) if cars.name in ["VW", "Poodle"]), 0)`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, actually no, the OP is looking for  a substring also

Comment: @Har, what exactly do you want to do, not sure I fully understand the logic, do you just want to make sure there is some particular car name in car names in cars?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham yes, im trying to find a substring for instance Poodle in "VW Poodle" or VW in "Poodle VW" or VW in "VW"

Comment: @Har, well i added a few more examples to my answer using different logic to get the same result as your code and how to get the actual index of the car

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Thanks its a great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you can do something like this:

```
tmp =  [index
        for index, name in enumerate([car.name for car in cars]) 
        if "VW" in car.name or "Poodle" in car.name]
carIndex = [0] if len(tmp)==0 else tmp
```

Tell me if you don't understand, or if it's not what you want.

Comment: OP would like to avoid tmp variable.

Comment: @jeanrjc yes I would like to avoid a temporary value, however it still is an interesting answer, I have not seen the [0] notation before without a variable name attached to it.

Comment: if you don't want the tmp, you can replace it by the list comprehension, but it will redo the for loop. `[0]` is just a list with `0` in it, I understood that if you had no match (empty list comprehension), you wanted that.

Comment: @jeanrjc yes but I would prefer to do it in a single statement or expression without having to redo the list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple way to do it if you **REALLY** doesn't want to use a temporary variable, but those are a bit *non-pythonic*.

Here is one, using lambda:

```
carIndex = (lambda x: 0 if not len(x) else x[1])(insert_list_comprehension_here)
```

**EDIT:** One *pythonic* way would be to use a `try-except`.

```
try:
    carIndex = [my_list_comprehension][1]
except IndexError:
    carIndex = 0
```